# Changing a link when a button is focused

Tags: javascript, if-statement, button, hyperlink

Basically I am going with an application style site for mobile view and they wanted a button on the bottom to flip through the pages in order while the nav at the top allows you to flip through them in any order. I want to change the bottom button to link to the following page depending on which one it is on. so I want the button to change links when specific buttons are focused. I tried many different things and can not seem to make it work. Please do your magic.

```
if(document.getElementById("abt").hasFocus()) {
document.getElementById("golink").href = "#work";
```

}

Comment: Do you know what focus is? It's just a user's interaction will be directed to whatever has focus until the user changes focus or blur event happens.What is the difference between a link that changes it's `href` to `http://xwz.com` when focused and a link that constantly has a href to `xyz.com`?  Wouldn't the user trigger the focus event just by using it? There is one way I guess by trigger but that sounds as useless as the former idea. Or am I missing something, besides the lack of a [mcve]?

Comment: I am trying to change the link of 1 button while another is focused

Comment: Ok, that makes much more sense, but there are better ways than focus unless you are using forms or tabbing is important.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe `focus` is what you're looking for as focus can be fleeting to track outside of form objects.

I've mocked up a possible solution to help aid you to what you're looking for.

Here is a link to the JSFiddle:

EDIT - Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t0uwff4t/

Javascript in the fiddle:

```
// Array of sections.
var sections = [
  '#first',
  '#second',
  '#third',
  '#fourth',
  '#fifth'
]

// Get the last value in the array.
var lastArrayValue = sections[sections.length - 1];

// Button pointer
var btn = document.querySelector('#button');

// On click of the button, do work.
btn.onclick = function() {
    // Get the current href.
  var href = btn.getAttribute('href');

  // Ternary operator setting the index to zero if the user is on the last index of array.
  // Else set the index to the next array value.
  var index = (href === lastArrayValue) ? 0 : sections.indexOf(href) + 1;

  // Set the href attribute.
  btn.setAttribute('href', sections[index]);
}
```

NOTE: While this example works, this is only a mockup - meaning that it doesn't account for rapid button clicking by the user to 'flip pages'.

Good luck and I hope this helps you to your goal.